# Little o properties. A question. Is what I am doing correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x)=o(x^m)$ as $x\to0$. In addition, $\lim_{x\to 0}{h(x)\over x}\in\Bbb{R}$. Prove $f(h(x))=o(x^m)$ as $x\to0$.

Here's how I started. I would appreciate corrections and hints:
Since $\lim_{x\to 0}{h(x)\over x}\in\Bbb{R}$ then I can denote $\lim_{x\to 0}{h(x)\over x}=L\in\Bbb{R}$. Therefore,$\lim_{x\to 0}{h(x)\over x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}{{h(x)\over x}\over x}=\lim_{x\to 0}{L\over x}=\infty\Rightarrow$ $h(x)=o(x^2)$ (big o or little o, in this case?) as  $x\to0$. Is that useful? How shall I continue?

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is a little-$o$ statement. So the first thing you should probably do is write it out using the definition of little-$o$, to see what it is you need to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the statement that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to saying that $h(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$ (big-oh of $x$). The fact that $f(x) = o(x^{m})$ as $x \to 0$ means that $f(x) = x^{m}g(x)$ where $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. We want to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(f(x))}{x^{m}} = 0$. Using the substitution $s = x^{m}g(x)$ I believe will do the trick. Note that $s \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{h(f(x))}{x^{m}} & = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{h(x^{m}g(x))}{x^{m}}\\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)\frac{h(s)}{s}\\
& = \lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \cdot \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{h(s)}{s}\\
& = 0 \cdot L = 0.
\end{align*}

--Edit--

So one was actually supposed to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(h(x))}{x^m} = 0.$ We know that $h(x) = q(x)x$ where $q$ is bounded near $x=0$. Thus
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(h(x))}{x^m}
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x q(x))}{x^m} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} q(x)^m \frac{f(s)}{s^m}.
\end{align}

Boundedness of $q$ means $|q(x)| \leq M$ for $|x| \leq \epsilon$. By the squeeze theorem $s = q(x)x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Applying the squeeze theorem again to the limit of interest then shows what we want.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a complete solution to me.

Comment: He didn't ask for all the details, but now I've added them.

Comment: That is a great answer.. 
Still I was wrong and it supposed to $f(h(x))$... I am so terribly sorry. It was a mistake. But don't feel bad about it, I have learned a lot from this trick.